# startup mount exclusive

Tags: oracle, startup, mount

What does the following command do?

```
startup mount **exclusive**;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deprecated .. now use STARTUP MOUNT

http://psoug.org/reference/start_stop.html

If your Oracle server allows multiple instances to access a single database concurrently (Oracle Parallel Server option), choose whether to mount the database exclusively or in parallel.

If you specify EXCLUSIVE (the default), then the database can only be mounted and opened by the current instance.

Taken from: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a76956/start.htm#6155

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I know that it is deprecated... But i still want to know what does it do? I also no that another option is "startup mount parallel;" But what is it for don't know:(